# How to get result from AsyncTask without blocking UI thread?

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have external class extending `AsyncTask` to get string from website to parse it as `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`. Currently i am using method `.get()` to get the result, but app is dropping frames, while waiting for server to respond. I want to use it reusable because I am getting data from many different classes.
My Asynctask class:

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            Log.d("Response: ", "> Establishing Connection" );
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }}
```

Now i am getting data by simply:

```
    String result = new JsonTask().execute(url).get();
```

Comment: @RichArt - Perhaps because `AsyncTask.execute()` returns the async task instance itself, not a `String` or any other kind of result.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for the get method:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Therefore it will block the UI until it finishes the background task which will return the result.

You can create a listener that accepts the return value of the `doInBackground` in your `JsonTask` which the `onPostExecute` will call the listener.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) again .

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

1. onPreExecute()
2. doInBackground(Params...)
3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.